# Android search error with sqllite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

im trying to use MATCH key word to get a cursor from query result from my database the query as follows

```
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database= databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    data = database.query(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, Constants.FROM_MAINSCREEN, databaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE + " MATCH ?", new String[]{"f*"}, null, null, null);
    if(data!=null)
        data.moveToFirst();
    dataAdapter = new MyCursorAdapterMainScreen(this, data, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I get error as follow

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing database
```

Comment: try to print the string value of query and check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: SQL logic error or missing
>   database

Your problem is your query and exactly `MATCH`, it won't work<sup>1</sup>. So change it to:

```
"... LIKE ?", new String[] {"f%"}
```

and now it should work.

<sup>1</sup> Match is introduced only with FTS3 and FTS4 tables so your table must be virtual and not ordinary as you most likely have.

Comment: can you tell what the diffrence is between a virtual table and an ordinary one

Comment: @coderVishal check [this out](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). It's long thread.

Answer (score 0):

By default, [`MATCH` is not implemented](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match() application-defined function. The default match() function implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for anything. But extensions can override the match() function with more helpful logic.

Looks like you could use `GLOB` instead of `MATCH`.